# Reasons for TLS Client Hello not being answered

Tags: c, ftp, tls1.2

I have written a basic TLS client for use in embedded systems (written in C). It uses TLS1.2, and it works great in 90% of situations. I have it working fine for HTTPS, and also have it working with various FTP servers using implicit and explicit FTPS. This week I've encountered an issue when using it with Cerberus FTP and proftpd though. TLS handshake goes through absolutely fine when opening the control channel on port 21, but when using passive mode and opening the passive port, my client sends the TLS Client hello (and I can see the server reply with a TCP ACK), but the FTP server never replies with a Server Hello. Does anyone know of a reason why that might be?-I'm guessing that there is something different in the way Cerberus and ProFTPd have implemented TLS that my client doesn't cater to. My client hello on both connections is identical (apart from port number in tcp headers) and I am not reusing the session data. I don't have this issue when testing against vsftpd or filezilla servers.

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason for the lack of response, and it's an interesting one if anyone is ever writing their own FTP Client and need to use FTPS with it. The FTP Client I had written issued the PASV command, and then immediately opened the data channel port before then issuing the STOR command on the control channel. This behaviour is fine for all FTP servers when using un-encrypted FTP. However, as I discovered, you have to beware when using TLS. With proftpd and cerberus FTP, the FTP server doesn't seem to attach a listener to that port until you issue the STOR command (or equivalent), so it won't negotiate TLS on that port until you've issued the command, whereas other FTP servers like vsftpd and filezilla are happy to negotiate TLS as soon as the port is opened. SO the solution was to open the port after sending the STOR command.